# Keycloak theme migration 3.4 - 4.5

Tags: docker, jboss, themes, keycloak

I am trying to add a theme to jboss/keycloak:4.5.0-Final

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:4.5.0.Final
COPY myTheme.zip /opt/jboss/
COPY myTheme-custom.cli /opt/jboss/
COPY myTheme-custom-cli.cmd /opt/jboss/
RUN cd /opt/jboss && keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=myTheme-custom.cli && rm -rf /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone_xml_history
```

myTheme-custom.cli

```
embed-server --server-config=standalone.xml --std-out=echo
run-batch --file=myTheme-custom-cli.cmd
stop-embedded-server
```

myTheme-custom-cli.cmd

```
module add --name=xxx.myTheme --resources=/opt/jboss/myTheme.zip
/subsystem=keycloak-server/theme=defaults:write-attribute(name=modules,value=[xxx.myTheme])
#Set the global default theme
/subsystem=keycloak-server/theme=defaults/:write-attribute(name=default,value=myTheme)
```

`myTheme.zip` is created following this [article](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_single_sign-on/7.0/html/server_developer_guide/themes)

This works fine with 3.4, but is just absent without warn/error in 4.5.

Did I miss any migration note?

EDIT: This works if I change `standalone.xml` to `standalone-ha.xml`.

Comment: did you ever find the problem?  we are having a similar issue

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/pull/151) has something to do with it.